# Angular 2- Parent with multiple children

Tags: angular, parent-child

I have a situation where at first seemed fairly straight forward to myself but after a couple of days changing my solution structure it has become so convoluted!
Well I have a got a parent/child component relationship as following:

- Parent

  - Child 1

    - Grandchild 1
    - Grandchild 2
    - Grandchild 3
  - Child 2

    - Grandchild 1
    - Grandchild 2
    - Grandchild 3

Each of these components (parent, child and grand child) has a property as "isValid" and a "validate()" method. All I want to achieve is a solution in which each component validity state depends on its own validate logic PLUS validity of all children component. 
Here is a simple validation rules for each component:

- Parent isValid = true if all children and grandchildren are valid
- Child isValid = true if number of its children neither more than 3 and nor less than 1 Plus all children are valid
- grandchild isValid = true if the textbox within it has a value

I have already read this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes and tried all possible ways it describes but neither fits my requirements of having the parent level component valid if ALL its children are valid!

thanks for your advice in advance :)

Comment: more details here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452328/angular-2-nested-depended-parent-child-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved it by bind components together via a service. in the way that all validation logic is located in the service and all parent, children and grand children validation flags are bound to that service.

eg. in grand children:

```
this.subscription = this.validationService.onValidateEvent.subscribe(data => { this.isValid = this.validationService.validate(this.timeOfDay); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify why [the official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes) didn't help you..

Basically you need to follow the [master/detail](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html)  guide.

I guess I would have done it with couple of Boolean array's...

Last say 'parent' has an array of 2, representing it's two children.

So

```
parentValid:boolean[]=[false,false];
```

Every child has the same concept for it's children (Mark as grandchildren)

```
childValid:boolean[]=[false,false,false];
```

The grandchild should only have an emitter witch notify it's parent on valid change. On every event like that, update `childValid` and do your logic there (More then 3 nor less then 1...) and emit the result to it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you mention you can use [parent-listens-for-child-event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-listens-for-child-event). In each child you will have an EventEmitter like so:

```
@Output() isValid = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

validate(valid: boolean) {
    this.isValid.emit(valid);
  }
```

that will be de-validated through a button for example:

```
<button (click)="validate(true)">Make child Valid</button>
```

The parent binds an event handler that responds to the child event payload $event and calculates its own validity:

```
children_valid:boolean[]; // for each parent children_valid.length==number_of_children
valid:boolen;
onValidate(valid: boolean, child_number: number) {
   this.children_valid[child_number-1]=valid;
   this.children_valid.some(x=>x==false) ? this.valid=false : this.valid=true
}

// Inside the template of the parent:
<my-child1
  (onValidate)="onValidate($event,1)">
</my-child1>
<my-child2
  (onValidate)="onValidate($event,2)">
</my-child2>
<my-child3
  (onValidate)="onValidate($event,3)">
</my-child3>
```

If a component is a parent and a child it must emit and receive an event when something changes.

Comment: thanks for your very descriptive response. I have figured out a solution based on your tip, but there are still a couple of wonders: 1) when each child is loaded I need to call the validate function in its parent to see if the child is valid as there is a button which is bound to the child isValid property and should get disabled if the child is not valid. where/when exactly should I call the validation function?!

Comment: It seems like a lifecycle hook case and in particular a ngOnInit: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#spy). You create a hook and you bound it to the button like: `<button (click)="validate(true) [disabled]="!valid"">Make child Valid</button>`. The validate function I provided is in the child so it would be better if I could see the code you have to better understand the problem. If the problem persists please accept this answer and open a new detailed question.

Comment: I have just tried your solution but the problem is that I do not have button on the parent and child component to run the validation cycle from the grandchildren upwards. The only button is located on the grandchildren which would trigger the validation cycle. Therefore the validity of the higher level components (Parent and children) cannot be set before setting the validity of all inside grandchildren.  As a result a grandchild cannot trigger its parent validate function prior having all its peers populated.

Comment: Since you have a button in the grandchild the grandchild will have to emit any change to the child it belongs as described in the answer. Then the child would have to receive the value as a parent of the grandchild (with an eventHandler) and at the same time emit its state-change to the overall parent after calculating it. The parent will handle these events coming from its children and calculate its state.